# Attaining a fundamental understanding of the Asynchronous Full Transfer Zone procedure

Tags: networking, dns, internet, domain

This is one of those concepts that I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around. I'm not even sure what explicit question to ask here. I have scoured google and the local search on stack, but can't find anything to clear AXFR for me. Here is what I understand:

A DNS server has a single simple purpose: to resolve URL names such as abc.com or 123.net with IP addresses(IPv4 with A records; IPv6 with AAAA records). Lets call these URL names Domain names. These Domain names can have subdomains such as m.123.net or z.abc.com. Each Domain/Subdomain has X amount of information. In order to practice redundancy in a network(avoiding a single point of failure), these domains are separated into zones; DNS servers are thus broken down into Primary and Secondary DNS zones, responsible for containing the domain zone information.

Moving to AXFR. The purpose of this procedure is to update all secondary DNS zones from a single point, thus eliminating the amount of admin work required to update this information manually on each server. Here is where I get lost...These servers use a key(rndc??) to perform this procedure.

Through my studies I have seen records being retrieved via the 'dig' command using the axfr option. I don't understand how this is possible without the rndc key. So I suppose my questions are:
Is the rndc key used for encrypting DNS server communication?
What is the difference between querying DNS records via AXFR vs a regular query(seeking record A for simple domain name resolution to IPv4)?
How is it possible to retrieve domain information via AXFR without the rndc key?

Comment: Zones transfer is for administrative configuration tasks to distribute full zone copies to secondary servers. It's not for ordinal dns client's queries.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between querying DNS records via AXFR vs a regular query(seeking record A for simple domain name resolution to IPv4)?

The difference is that an `AXFR` request will cause the server to return **all** records within a zone in response to just a single query.

This means that replica servers can start without any knowledge about the zone's contents – they don't need to be told what subdomains exist in the zone (or which ones were just added/removed); as you mentioned, "eliminating the amount of admin work required to update this information manually on each server" is the point of a full transfer.

Additionally, with a zone transfer, the secondary nameservers don't need to individually query every single subdomain to detect updates (a zone could have thousands of records – and not all of them are of type A, either). They only query the "serial number" in the SOA record, and if that changed, the entire zone is refreshed in a single transfer.

(In addition to "full transfer" AXFR requests, many nameservers also implement incremental transfer, where only the differences between old and new serial numbers are sent.)

> How is it possible to retrieve domain information via AXFR without the rndc key?

Whether a key is *needed* is an individual decision by the nameserver admin. Many zones don't actually use TSIG for transfers – they only use IP address restrictions, i.e. "trusted" IPs can transfer the zone without a key, everyone else cannot transfer it at all.

But if the zone's administrator has set up a TSIG key as being required, then you cannot get around that requirement. In that case, zone transfers between servers are possible because the secondary servers in fact *have the key.*

(Note that this isn't the rndc key – it happens to be the same key *type,* but rndc is only for local control of the BIND nameserver, whereas for DNS requests it's called a TSIG key.)

Some admins deliberately leave zone transfer available to everyone, for example `gnu.org` can be transferred without restrictions (from one of its nameservers). `ihtfp.com` is another such site.

- Linux:

  ```
  dig gnu.org AXFR @ns2.gnu.org
  ```
- Windows (doesn't work all that well, due to bugs in nslookup):

  ```
  nslookup
  > server 209.51.188.163
  > ls -d gnu.org
  ```

Comment: By "all records" I'm assuming you mean returning subdomain names associated with the initial domain being queried? As opposed to simply receiving a resolved IP for the name being queried? Also, just to clarify, each zone has an SOA record associated with the zone file; if this file has an outdated serial, an AXFR request is made to the Primary zone to update the serial, thus getting updated data on the domain within the zone. Is this right?

Comment: By "records" I mean the whole 'subdomain name + record type + value' units. The zone transfer gives you all names *and* their associated data at the same time. (Also, DNS can store a bit more than just IPs...) AXFRs are indeed triggered by the serial number being different, although I would say the purpose of AXFR isn't specifically "to update the serial", it's to transfer the zone, and the serial just gets updated as part of that (because you transfer the SOA record as well).

Comment: Okay. So if I did a dig command using the axfr option, I'm asking @the.name.server to pull the zone files associated with the domain name specified? If that server is not configured to perform this action, I get some kind of error in response, otherwise it will retrieve the zone file and display its contents? The contents can be A records, the SOA record, MX, etc?

Comment: ...and that's all apposed to performing a normal query for A or AAAA records where I get an IPv4 or IPv6 address if successful? I have questions about forwarding but I'll save it for another time. Thank you for your time! I'm very grateful for your shared knowledge.

Comment: Yes, you get either the zone's contents (not the raw file but the processed records) or a 'REFUSED' error code.